Mapster exceptions aren't clear when mapping fails during runtime
Is there something I could do to get more meaningful exceptions?
My mapping code looks like this:
config.NewConfig<MyEntity, MyDto>()
   .Map(p => p.MyDateAsDateTime, p => p.MyDateAsString)
   .Compile();

There's no indication on which property mapping the error occurred. If my configuration has 20 property mappings for the same class, I need to guess, disable some mappings to semi-randomly find the problem.
Here's for example a format exception I'm getting when a string fails to be converted into DateTime by mapster.
String '' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
System.FormatException:
   at lambda_method30 (Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at lambda_method33 (Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at MapsterMapper.ServiceMapper.Map (Mapster.DependencyInjection, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e64997d676a9c1d3)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext (System.Linq, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter+<WriteResponseBodyAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson, Version=8.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter+<WriteResponseBodyAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson, Version=8.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter+<WriteResponseBodyAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson, Version=8.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeResultAsync>g__Logged|22_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0>d`2.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__11.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware+<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI, Version=6.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4232c99127b3c254)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger, Version=6.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=62657d7474907593)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Op.ClientHelpers.Configuration.ApplicationBuilderExtensions+<>c+<<UseAlwaysOn>b__3_0>d.MoveNext (Op.ClientHelpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /home/vsts/work/1/s/Source/Op/Op.ClientHelpers/Configuration/ApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs:33)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Op.ClientHelpers.Configuration.ApplicationBuilderExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass0_0+<<UseUppMetadataHeaders>b__0>d.MoveNext (Op.ClientHelpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /home/vsts/work/1/s/Source/Op/Op.ClientHelpers/Configuration/ApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs:15)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1+<ProcessRequestAsync>d__2.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)```


The exception is clear, It tells you that the empty string cannot be converted to a datetime.
You have to solve the binding problem that makes the MyDateAsString property an empty string.

Please read my question once again. This the important bit: "There's no indication on which property mapping the error occurred. If my configuration has 20 property mappings for the same class, I need to guess, disable some mappings to semi-randomly find the problem.". The error should indicate no which mapping exactly the problem occurred.
